# Annotate/Reward posts with audio samples?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I'm not really sure this question makes sense but since we are now re-designing the whole thing wouldn't it be cool to have a way to know or give some sort of reward to posts that contain audio samples?

There are some other questions regarding this issue and I think we all have been writing answers to problems we've never "listened" to.. so audio samples are vital to some questions being asked here.

I don't even know if it's possible though :)

Comment: _"I'm not really sure this question makes sense"_ - 10 points! ;) I don't get it, really. Like what rewards would they get? I thought about making monthly "best question/answer" meta posts a while back. Is that the sort of thing you mean?

Comment: Maybe it's my lack of knowledge about SO in general. But it'd be nice to promote sound sample uploading/attaching :)

Comment: Yeah, I know what you mean there. Maybe we could include it in question help text. We need to redesign the [first-time asker modal thing](https://sound.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1501/14770) anyway to help quell the tide of off-topic hardware questions, so maybe we could fit it in there too.

Answer (score 4):

Well, we aren't "redesigning the whole thing." for a start. We are ust getting the graphic design template that used to come with site graduation. That's it.

Also, "rewarding" is not necessary in any case - if we need to hear a sound we ask the OP to post a link to a sample. If the question or answer is good it gets upvotes, which are the reward.

You can always add a bounty if you like - that's always an option.

Answer (score 1):

A whole lot of the posts that include sound bites or video links are nothing more than "What's this effect/sound?"

I don't think we should be rewarding people who replace actual research effort with copy/paste YouTube links.

Sure, there are times when a link will help, but there are many more that are an excuse to not bother explaining the issue in searchable text.