# WE need YOUR suggestions for help text (#1 - "Asking a good question")

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions

<kbd>**TL;DR** To help stem the tide of bad/off-topic Q's, we need your
suggestions for help text which
 pops up for users asking a question for the first time (see [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/377059/339339) and related [sister meta post](https://sound.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1503/14770)).</kbd>

Yes, we need YOUR thinker to give us words! How important do YOU feel now? Your words could be a permanent fixture on our site! Helping swathes of confused users stumbling in the dark! Your shimmering words lighting up the path, slowly but definitively spelling out your immortal words… *"JOG ON, YOU'RE NOT WELCOME HERE"* …or, you know, whatever you want it to say. There are no "wrong" answers, I suppose.

ENOUGH! To business...

Given the recent tidal-wave of off-topic questions asking things like "how do I pick my teeth with my 1/8" headphone jack?", it's about time we customized these snippets of guidance that adorn the question asking process. These helpful chunks of information are the same for all SE communities, but can be customized if needed, as many other communities have done. The right help text at the right moment will help quell the tide in a clear, tight and informative way.

**There are TWO such help text displays we can customize:**

**1. The *"Asking a good question"* modal. (which we're discussing right here ↓)**

[image: Asking a good question help modal on SDSE]

**2. The *"Step 1: Draft your question"* right-panel help pane. (which we're discussing in a [sister meta post](https://sound.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1503/14770))**

[image: Draft your question help text on SDSE]

---

### The "Asking a good question" modal…

[image: Default "Asking a good question" modal]

#### What is the "Asking a good question" modal?

This modal pops up when a user asks their first question. It's the same for all sites, but we do have the option of changing some of the text to make it more in-line with our site-specific guidelines. (if you want to see the modal - use a private web browser and click "ask a question" as I did above)

#### What can we change?

Please read [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/377059/339339), it explains things way better than I ever could!
Read it? Good… So in summary, we can change the first two paragraphs and remove the last bullet point, if we wish to do so. Although it's a bit more work, we can add HTML to the paragraphs (lists, links, etc) - refer back to the real world examples in [the answer you just read](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/377059/339339).

#### Why does it need to change?

We are getting a lot of questions where the user doesn't seem to have read or understood what is on-topic and what isn't. We get questions about home theatre, consumer stuff like mobile apps and questions asking how to do something on a particular device which can be found easily in the manual or with a quick Google search. So we need to add more explicit guidelines in the help text. Hopefully the user will read it before they post.

#### Some real-life DATA to hone your sword against:

**Closed Questions**
I encourage you to spend some time scrolling through [this list of closed questions](https://sound.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=closed%3A1) to get an idea of what **close reasons** pop up regularly and what could be said to these users to collectively *nip these questions in the bud*.

**Bad Questions**
In addition, it would be helpful to scroll through [this list of questions with a negative score](https://sound.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=votes%3A..-1%20is%3Aquestion) to get an idea of **bad questions**, and what could be said to these users to *help improve their questions*.

### Finally…

Please read [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/377059/339339) mentioned earlier before submitting any suggestions, it's extremely informative on the subject and the process and includes successful examples from other communities.

**Answers**
You can give full answers, or you can just suggest points you think should be included or sentences or paragraphs to consider.
[The community answer](https://sound.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1502/14770) can then be updated with any popular suggestions.

You can even vote to **not change** the *"Asking a good question"* help text modal if you wish. If there is already a *"don't change it"* answer, just upvote and give your reasoning in a comment.

I'll start the ball rolling with the [community wiki answer](https://sound.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1502/14770) - this is where we'll mould the suggestions to a complete answer. Feel free to add your own complete answer, though - it will be just as valid an answer.

**Timescale**
If we get support for a particular layout after a month, we'll pass it to the CMs for review.

**This is your chance to help mould our site into a better repository of knowledge for the world of sound design and production!**

Answer (score 1):

<sup>**Community Example**: Can be updated and changed as more suggestions come in.</sup>
**DEFAULT:**
[image: Asking a good question modal]

**REVISED:**

#### Asking a good question

You are ready to ask your first question, and the community is here to help! To get the best answers, we've provided some guidance:

While we'd love to hear from you, remember, this is a **Professional/Enthusiast** community and as such:

- This site is **NOT** for consumer audio questions
- We are **NOT** here to read equipment manuals and search Google for you (maybe ask the manufacturer?)
- We **ARE** here to help with...(?) your sound design and production questions that others would find helpful(?)
- We expect a detailed, well researched question with links to audio clips where appropriate.

**Before posting:** Make sure your question is [**on-topic**](https://sound.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and hasn't been answered. **If you're still unsure, request advice in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=sound.stackexchange.com).**

When you're ready to write your first question, be sure to:

1. Summarize the problem
2. Provide details and any research
3. When appropriate, describe what you've tried

Answer (score 0):

"If there isn't a suitable tag, it's likely off-topic"

Comment: I'm not so sure about this - I'm a supporter of creating a tag once enough questions on that topic make it worthwhile, but that doesn't mean a lack of tag means it's off topic.

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right there ;)